# UFW Enabled, but not starting upon Pi reboot

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot, security

I am running servers on several Pi's for VPN, OpenTTD, etc. I have installed ufw on all of them to try and keep them a little more secure. The server running the VPN is causing some issues as ufw doesn't start after a reboot, even though it is supposedly enabled.

Here is `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf`:

```
# /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
#

# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=yes

# Please use the 'ufw' command to set the loglevel. Eg: 'ufw logging medium'.
# See 'man ufw' for details.
LOGLEVEL=high
```

Running `sudo ufw status` after a reboot I get:

```
Status: inactive
```

But running `systemctl status ufw` I get:

```
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-03-27 02:06:36 GMT; 4min 46s ago
     Docs: man:ufw(8)
  Process: 104 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 104 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ufw.service

Mar 27 02:06:36 PiVPN systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

If I manually disable ufw and then try to re-enable it, I get the following error (The `sudo ufw enable` is done after a reboot):

```
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
ip6tables-restore: line 2 failed
```

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT 01:** I have tried running `sudo /usr/share/ufw/check-requirements` and after some output, I get a message that `All tests passed`.

**EDIT 02:** I have done a complete re-install of ufw using `sudo apt remove --purge ufw`, and after installing it again the problem still persists.

Comment: have you tried `sudo ufw reload` and `sudo ufw enable`?

Comment: @Dougie If I run `sudo ufw reload` after a reboot, It says `Firewall not enabled (skipping reload)`. If I manually enable it, I still get the same error: ```ERROR: problem running ufw-init
ip6tables-restore: line 2 failed```.

Comment: @Dougie sorry I should clarify, when I said "If I manually enable it", I meant if I manually do `sudo ufw enable` and then `sudo ufw reload`. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was found after a lot of digging. This [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ufw/+bug/521359) explained that ufw was trying to start before all of the network interfaces were up. This can be negated by doing one of the following:

**From the Terminal**
 1. Type `sudo raspi-config`
 2. Select `Boot Options` (Option 3)
 3. Select `Wait for Network at Boot` (Option B2)
 4. Select `Yes`

**From the Desktop**
 1. Click `Menu` at the top left of the screen (The small raspberry icon)
 2. Select `Preferences`
 3. Select `Raspberry Pi Configuration`
 4. Check the box next to `Wait for network`

Then enable ufw again and try rebooting. Use `sudo ufw status` to see if it has started.